# App's Properties loses data when closing the app

Tags: xamarin, properties, xamarin.forms, navigation

I am using below code to store the user login details:

```
App.Current.Properties.Add("ZeeraCustomerID", loginuserdata[0].customer_id);
App.Current.Properties.Add("ZeeraCustomerFirstName", loginuserdata[0].first_name);
App.Current.Properties.Add("ZeeraCustomerLastName", loginuserdata[0].last_name);
App.Current.Properties.Add("ZeeraCustomerEmail", loginuserdata[0].email_address);
App.Current.Properties.Add("ZeeraCustomerCountry", loginuserdata[0].country_code);
await App.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
```

and in every page I am using:

```
if (!App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("ZeeraCustomerID"))
{
    Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new ZeeraSignin()));
}
```

To check if the user is loggedon otherwise prompt with the Signin page

It works perfectly when I login the same time and as long as I don't close the app or restart the phone but as soon as I close my app or restart the device then it loses the data and it prompts me to sign in which is not the correct behavior.

Comment: call App.Current.SavePropertiesAsync() to force a save

Comment: Saving the data should work exactly as you have implemented. Are sure the app is not uninstalled from the device with each deploy?

Comment: I am already calling SavePropertiesAsync ...  The app is not uninstalled, I am using it from TestFlight as well and all I am doing is closing the app and going to another app or restarting the device..